# How to find the maximum angle of the second-largest angle in a triangle given two sides

Tags: trigonometry

I've come across a question that I'm unsure why my solution works:

In triangle $ABC$, $AC=30cm$, and $BC = 40cm$. Find the greatest measure of angle $B$.

Drawing out the triangle shows that angle $A$ will be the biggest (as it's opposite to the longest side), and followed by $B$ because I want to maximize this. So, I setup a Pythagorean triangle with $40$ being the hypotenuse, and $30$ the side length opposite to B. This gives me the correct answer of $$48.6^{\circ}$$

However, how can I show that setting up a right-angled triangle like this will provide the biggest $B$ possible? Are there any other ways to do it? It's found in my sine law / cosine law part of the textbook, if that helps.

Comment: Using the hint that this question may be related to your sine law / cosine law:

$$\frac{\sin B}{AC} = \frac{\sin A}{BC}$$

and the maximum of $\sin A$ is $1$, when $A = 90^\circ$.

Comment: " (as it's opposite to the longest side)"  Says who? What if $AB > 40$?

Answer (score 0):

Using the law of sines, $$\frac{\sin B}{AC} = \frac{\sin A}{BC}$$ Substituting the given values for $AC$ and $BC$ gives
$$\frac{\sin B}{30} = \frac{\sin A}{40}$$ so $$\sin B = \frac{30 \sin A}{40}$$
This means that $\sin B$ is directly proportional to $\sin A$, which means that when $\sin A$ is maximized, $\sin B$ will also be maximized. Hence, since $\sin A$ is maximized when $A = 90 ^\circ$
(because $\sin 90 ^\circ = 1$), then $\sin B = \frac{30(1)}{40}$ so $B \approx 48.6 ^\circ$.